# jQuery functionality with .on not functioning from dropdown

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a dropdown that does an ajax call to dynamically load a page in:

```
<script>
$("#dropdownchoice").change(function(e) {
   var $dropdown = $(this);

   $(".simple_form").remove();

  $.get('/dropchoice/option/' + $dropdown.val(), function(data) {
    $dropdown.after(data);
  });
});
</script>
```

And it pulls a set of questions into the page .dropchoice/option/ without reloading. But, on the page of questions we want to do a few jQuery things: form validation, etc. One of which is simply pulling everything that isn't a number / letter.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).on('click',"#dropdownchoice",function(){ 
$(".form").keyup(function(event) {
   name = jQuery(".form").val();
   name = name.replace(/[^a-zA-Z 0-9]+/g, '');
  jQuery(".form").val(name);
});
});
</script>
```

But, I've tried so many different versions of this and still can't get it to load after the initial dropdown. I've done .on / ajaxComplete / etc. Any ideas? I am sure I am missing something extremely simple.

Comment: click != change and every time it is clicked, you are adding another keyup handler to the .form element, hopefully that is being replaced.

Comment: Then what would you recommend? The user makes a choice from the dropdown that I then dynamically pull in, but on that page has to be this script so all I could thing was "click".

Comment: So when they pick a value, change will fire.

Comment: So what is the problem? I am lost. So you are wondering why the keyup is not being applied to the new content? Why are you not using event delegation there?

Comment: The problem is that it isn't loading the script / the script isn't working. Didn't know about event delegation, looking now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62700/discussion-between-nathanielelliott-and-epascarello).